# Docusign: IHttpContextAccessor alternate in normal C# web api without core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

I have asp.net core example of git-hub for embedded signing.

How should I convert code for normal C# web API. I am getting error for IHttpContextAccessor,IMemoryCache and IConfiguration

While conversion I am getting error - "IHttpContextAccessor namespace could not be found."

Is there any alternate of IHttpContextAccessor  namespace that I can use in normal c# web API. I want to convert given below code -

```
    public RequestItemsService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IMemoryCache cache, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _cache = cache;
        Status = "sent";
        _apiClient = _apiClient ?? new ApiClient();
        var identity = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        if (identity != null && identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _id = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting .net framework then you should be able to swap `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` for `HttpContext.Current`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.8